# LUIS: Batch testing returning incorrect results for entities

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm training a LUIS model to recognize the intent to change the date of birth or expected date of birth for an individual in a database. In addition to a datetimeV2 entity it is expected that a number:MemberID or number:FamilyID will be detected too. If it isn't that will be handled programmically.

**Example Utterance** - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjXbM.png

My issue is that when batch testing LUIS it labels True Positive results for the builtin.number as False Positives. I don't know if this is a bug with LUIS or something wrong with my model or batch files. I've labeled screen shots below of the batch training results and will add a snippet from the batch test file.

I've attempted retraining the model and combining intents but no such luck. I've added up to 60 utterances for each intent but I end up with an over trained model with more problems than when I started. Additionally, I've added patterns but again this does not help.

**Batch Results Graph** - https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5ONN.png

**False Positive Utterances** - https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ30N.png

```
[
  {
    "text": "change dob to 09/16/2013 for Charles Patterson in family 53183",
    "intent": "ChangeDOB",
    "entities": [
      {
        "entity": "datetimeV2",
        "startPos": 14,
        "endPos": 24
      },
      {
        "entity": "FirstName",
        "startPos": 29,
        "endPos": 36
      },
      {
        "entity": "LastName",
        "startPos": 37,
        "endPos": 46
      },
      {
        "entity": "number:FamilyID",
        "startPos": 57,
        "endPos": 62
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "change birth dt for 47224 to 10/22/2015",
    "intent": "ChangeDOB",
    "entities": [
      {
        "entity": "number:MemberID",
        "startPos": 20,
        "endPos": 25
      },
      {
        "entity": "datetimeV2",
        "startPos": 29,
        "endPos": 39
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "repair birthday to 04/30/2019 in family 84842",
    "intent": "ChangeDOB",
    "entities": [
      {
        "entity": "datetimeV2",
        "startPos": 19,
        "endPos": 29
      },
      {
        "entity": "number:FamliyID",
        "startPos": 40,
        "endPos": 45
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "alter birthday to 01/18/2004 for Harry Taylor in family 31902",
    "intent": "ChangeDOB",
    "entities": [
      {
        "entity": "datetimeV2",
        "startPos": 18,
        "endPos": 28
      },
      {
        "entity": "FirstName",
        "startPos": 33,
        "endPos": 38
      },
      {
        "entity": "LastName",
        "startPos": 39,
        "endPos": 45
      },
      {
        "entity": "number:FamilyID",
        "startPos": 56,
        "endPos": 61
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "change date of birth to 11/15/2003 for 87546",
    "intent": "ChangeDOB",
    "entities": [
      {
        "entity": "datetimeV2",
        "startPos": 24,
        "endPos": 34
      },
      {
        "entity": "number:MemberID",
        "startPos": 39,
        "endPos": 44
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Ultimately, the batch results should be displaying True Positives for the utterances that it is currently labeled False Positives because they do contain a number:MemberID which it detects correctly.

Comment: would you be able to share the JSON of your LUIS model so we could test this ourselves in the LUIS portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you're using the entity role feature to label `number:MemberID` and `number:FamilyID` into subtypes, correct? If this is the case, then this is the reason why your batch tests are not working.

Specifically in the [LUIS docs on batch testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-batch-test#roles-in-batch-testing), it says this:

[image]

So it appears you cannot use batch testing to test utterances with these types of entities with roles.

You could request that this feature be worked on via [UserVoice](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-language-understanding-luis)--forum that helps our team get feedback from the community and perhaps help prioritize what features we should work on first.

Comment: I thought that may be the case. Thank you for confirming my suspicion!